# How can I make a div's contents wrap without setting an explicit width?

Tags: html, css, layout, width

I want to have a series of posts with titles and other information.  The problem is, depending on how much space the containing div has and how long the titles are, it is causing my "post-summary" (title, date, etc) div to wrap to the next line making it look like:

Here is what it is doing:
[image]

Here is what I want it to do (note the title wrapped, but didn't cause the whole "post-summary" to wrap to the next line like in the previous example):
[image]

I don't care how much the title wraps or how many lines it wraps to. I just don't want it to force the parent div which also contains the post-info to drop below the post number like it does in the first example.

I've created an example jsfiddle to further illustrate what I'm doing:
http://jsfiddle.net/aZvVU/6/

How can I make the post-titles simply wrap when it doesn't have enough space and not cause it to make the whole "post-summary" div from dropping to the next line?  I don't want to make the title width fixed if I can avoid it.

Comment: you mean it should show `...` ellipses if line is  longer then available space

Comment: No, I simply want it to wrap naturally onto the next line but without forcing its parent div "post-summary" to break onto the next line.  So the post date and title would still be to the right of the grey post number box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the floating on `.post-summary`, you don't need it and it is causing your wrapping. Then add `margin-left: 40px;` to `.post-summary` to ensure that there is room for the `.post-number` and give the illusion of a full height column for the `.post-number` without having to muck about the heights.

To sort out the navbar, drop the floating from `.post-list` and kill off your clearing `<div>`s. If you want the navbar to take up a whole column then add a `margin-right:220px` to `.post-list`.

For example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tGQeJ/1/ (without 220px right margin)
- http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tGQeJ/2/ (with has the 220px right margin)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a starting point http://jsfiddle.net/A8csU/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="right-child">
        <p>Right stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="left-child">
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It  has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it  over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at  Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure  Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through  the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the  undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33  of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by  Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of  ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem  Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section  1.10.32.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left-child {
 border: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: 102px; /* 100px + 1px border + 1px border */
}

#right-child {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can you look at the fiddle I provided?  I'm not sure what you have shown here really applies. Making these same tweaks still causes the post-summary to drop below the post-number.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a few tweaks to your code like so:

```
.post-list
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 250px;  /* make sure it doesn't touch your right-nav*/
}

.right-nav
{
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; /* position it */
}
```

Here is a working example, with your code http://jsfiddle.net/YumSP/

edited to fix title wrapping http://jsfiddle.net/YumSP/1/

Comment: That doesn't work.  The post-summary div (which contains both the post-title and post-info) is wrapping to below the post-number.

Comment: Edited the CSS.  The example now works with wrapping titles, etc.

Comment: @Viquinish if 'float:left' doesn't work for you, you need to put your example of jsfiddle.net to get further help on this.